# does asp.net mysql security still need other party library for Providers

Tags: asp.net, mysql, security

2 years ago i was using mysql security providers [membership,role] from code-project article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx

do we still need that or the current mysql-connector provide that? i saw something called [MySql.Web.dll] so is that a replacement or not!

please en-light and guide me,

thanks,

Comment: I still need more detailed answer!! nobody cares about bounty or anything these days!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL Providers. They work great. No need for other providers. The advantage of your custom provider is maybe just more flexibility. 
We customized our own provider, so we cannot switch.

Not sure what more you wanna know?

Comment: does mysql provider allow me to define my own tables regarding users and security permissions structure or i am forced to use there tables? what's the benefit of the other providers they have beside the membership and roles (like session one for example)?

Comment: No, the MySQL uses their own tables. If you wanna have your own structure, you have to run your own provider.
There is a SQL Session Provider for the MS SQL Server, this is similar for MySQL. It stores the session in the DB instead of in the RAM.

Comment: ok, one more point and bounty is yours, what custom provider you used? do you think the one i mentioned in the question is out dated or not [just in case you got time to check it] thanks.

Comment: This is the one I used. But I completely customized it to fit in with my data structure. Our CRM is directly coupled with the Provider.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still need a third party or custom build provider to connect to a MySQL database, check out http://schleichermann.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/asp-net-mysql-membership-provider/. This will walk you through using [MySQL .Net connectors](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html)

**EDIT** you can of course use the link you've provided in your question as well. I'm just not sure how out of date that might be.